# Integrate Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I'm a new one with azure functions! I need to add authentication and authorization to my Azure Function app (isolated process). But I don't know how I can configure everything in my Program.cs.

I tried something like this

```
public static IHostBuilder AddAzureAd(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
{
    return hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, collection) =>
    {
        collection.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "JwtBearer";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "JwtBearer";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("JwtBearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd:TenantId")}";
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudiences = new string[]
                    {
                        //Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd:A");
                        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd:Audience")!
                    },
                    ValidIssuers = new string[]
                    {
                        $"https://sts.windows.net/{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd:TenantId")}/",
                        $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd:TenantId")}/v2.0/"
                    },
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureAd:ClientSecret")!))
                };
            });

        // Configure authorization for the specified functions
        collection.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("JwtPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("JwtBearer");
                policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

And add authorize attribute to my function

```
[Authorize(Policy = "JwtPolicy")]
```

but it is still not working

Comment: Azure Functions is separate to Asp.Net. The Azure Functions SDK doesn't recognize most classes in the Asp.Net namespace, so all the configuration you are adding will simply not be used. The good news is the Azure portal offers easy integration with AAD in the 'Identity Providers' tab. Have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/authorizing-user-requests-in-azure-functions-with-azure-ad)

Comment: This tutorial shows how to integrate AAD, but I need to make some function public without needing to be authorized.

Comment: That's definitely possible with the native authentication. Have a look at [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#authorization-behavior)

Comment: I agree with Andrew Williamson's approach